# How to run audio editing program razor after having installed it?

Tags: software-installation, audio-recording

Please Vote to delete this questions, it is an error on my side, the name of the program is wrong, it is actually ReZound not razor!!!

my system:

- ubuntu 16.04 suite
- xface GUI
- standard repository plus a few ppa-s

After having performed `apt-get install razor` and `apt-cache policy razor` to check if it is installed, I tried to run it by the usual methods:

- typing **razor** at the command line
- typing **razor** into the graphical program browser
- right click to search for it in the context menu of xface

none of it worked,
in other words, I am run out of options, how can I make it run the apt-cache policy command tells me it is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, **razor** is not what you mean to use.

Description of what you have installed by typing `apt-get install razor`:

Vipul's Razor is a distributed, collaborative, spam detection and
filtering network. Razor establishes a distributed and constantly updating the catalog of spam in propagation...

For more information about **razor** use:
`man razor-client` or `man razor-admin`.

By searching the Internet, I found that there is no audio editing software with the title **razor**. So I recommend you to install an alternative audio editing software **audacity** by typing:

`apt-get install audacity`

Comment: Thank you very much, I must suffer from wrong memory disorder, because you are absolutely right about the name, there is no audio file editor with this name, the name turned out to be ReZound